# Constructor-Injected field is null in Spring CGLIB enhanced bean

Tags: java, spring

I have this repository:

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {

  private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

  public MyRepository(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
    this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
  }

  void doSomething() {
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(...);
  }
}
```

Which worked as expected with Spring Boot 1.4.5 (Spring Core & JDBC 4.3.7). When debugging `doSomething()`, I can see that the instance of `MyRepository` **is an ordinary object** and the `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` is set.

However, as soon as I update to Spring Boot 1.4.6 (Spring Core & JDBC 4.3.8) or higher, the instance of  `MyRepository` **is a `MyRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB`** and `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` is `null`. I see it being injected in the constructor, however, at that point my repository is not yet CGLIB enhanced.

Why is that? I couldn't find a hint in the [release 4.3.8 release notes](https://jira.spring.io/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&version=15892).

Comment: I assume you should try something like this
`@Autowired`
`public MyRepository(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {`
   `this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;`
`}`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't change anything. Also, [`@Autowired` is optional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html) and I do see the instance being injected. But the field becomes `null` when Spring creates its CGLIB enhanced bean.

Comment: it's just an assumption, but it seems that `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` is not a bean, 
so this may be the issue.

Comment: How would it get injected in the constructor if it's not a bean? How would it have worked with Spring 4.3.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I couldn't reproduce it in a minimal example, my [bug report](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15911) got accepted.

Answer (score 5):

I had something related. My methods were **final** and because of this, Spring was using CGLIB Proxied Classes instead of the default behavior (Spring AOP Proxied Classes). So to access the class properties, I had to call the getXXX() method, otherwise, the property would be returned **null** every time I've tried to access it.

Comment: This is a good answer – it not only tells us how to fix it, but also the background. Thank you!

Comment: This answer saved me hours of debugging!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem... I fixed my case by changing method to public instead of protected.

Have you tried

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {

  private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

  public MyRepository(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
    this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
// Check whether we only have one InvokerInterceptor: that is,
// no real advice, but just reflective invocation of the target.

if (chain.isEmpty() && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {

  /* 
    We can skip creating a MethodInvocation: just invoke the target directly.
    Note that the final invoker must be an InvokerInterceptor, so we know
    it does nothing but a reflective operation on the target and no hot
    swapping or fancy proxying.
  */
  Object[] argsToUse = AopProxyUtils.adaptArgumentsIfNecessary(method, args);
  retVal = methodProxy.invoke(target, argsToUse);

} else {

  // We need to create a method invocation.
  retVal = new CglibMethodInvocation(proxy, target, method, args, targetClass, chain, methodProxy).proceed();
}
```