# Spring Boot Bean: value passed in constructor is not null in constructor, but null in CGLIB proxy

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cglib

I have the following repository implementation in Kotlin:

```kotlin
@Repository
class SapArticleRepository(jooqDsl: DSLContext, jooqConfiguration: DefaultConfiguration) :
    AbstractSapRepository<TrmSapArticleRecord, TrmSapArticlePojo>(jooqDsl, jooqConfiguration)
```

with the following base class:

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractSapRepository<R : UpdatableRecord<R?>, TPojo>(
    var dao: DAOImpl<R, TPojo, Long>,
    jooqDsl: DSLContext,
    jooqConfiguration: DefaultConfiguration,
) {
    fun findById(id: Long) = dao.findById(id)
}
```

When running an Integration test, I get an exception, because `dao` is null. I checked (by debugging): `dao` is not null when the constructor is called, but it indeed is when `findById` is called. I noticed that the object references are not the same (because of CGLIB, the Spring proxy), but I don't know what happens between the constructor call and the time the proxied bean is created.

I tried an abstract function `getDaoImpl()` an which is implemented in `SapArticleRepository` (returning the object instance) and the calling that method (instead of accessing `dao`), but that seems overly complicated. There must be a way to pass the constructor argument/field in a way so it is still present by the time the Bean is used.

Note. `TrmSapArticleDao` is just a Jooq-generated class.

Edit: I already found [Constructor-Injected field is null in Spring CGLIB enhanced bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955727/constructor-injected-field-is-null-in-spring-cglib-enhanced-bean), but the accepted answer does not seem to answer my question.

Comment: Your method is final (i assume not that familiar with kotlin) ad thus doesn't pass through to the actual instance but is invoked on the proxy. The proxy (propbably for transactions or security) doesn't have its fields initialized because it should just add behavior and invoke the actual method on the real instance. However as a `final` or non `public` method cannot be proxied it will be invoked directly on the proxy. Which leads to the behavior you see.

Answer (score 0):

As always, I found the solution 5 minutes after posting the question...

The problem was that fields passed in the constructor are final in Kotlin by default. CGLIB can't intercept final fields/method and therefore leaves them initialized with `null` (see [this answer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20465#issuecomment-453460363) on GitHub.

The solution is to make the constructor field `open`. So above code works when defining the constructor of the abstract class as follows:

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractSapRepository<R : UpdatableRecord<R?>, TPojo>(
    open var dao: DAOImpl<R, TPojo, Long>,
    jooqDsl: DSLContext,
    jooqConfiguration: DefaultConfiguration,
)
```